# How do I change the widget on a manytomany ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have Book and a Category model with a manytomany relationship thru another model

```
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

class Book(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
   categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, through='book.BookCategory')

class BookCategory(models.Model):
   business = models.ForeignKey(Business)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   created = models.DateField()
```

Then my Forms look like this:

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length = 255)
    categories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        queryset =  Category.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Business
        fields = ('name', 'categories')
```

When I try to save an instance of the form
book_form = BookForm(request.POST, instance=business)
book_form.save()

I get this error:
Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.  Use book.BookCategory's Manager instead.

How would I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As you do not have any extra fields in `BookCategory`, you can remove the model and the `through='BookCategory'` argument. Then an implicit model will be created, an you should be able to use the widget.

Comment: I removed a bunch of stuff to make it leaner, the readl BookCategory has both a user and a created to keep track of who did what and when. I'v edited the question to reflect this